# Make a numpy array monotonic without a Python loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 1D array of values which is supposed to be monotonic (let's say decreasing), but there are random regions where the value increases with index.

I need an array where each region is replaced with a value directly preceding it, so that the resulting array is sorted.

So if given array is:

```
a = np.array([10.0, 9.5, 8.0, 7.2, 7.8, 8.0, 7.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0])
```

I want the result to be

```
b = np.array([10.0, 9.5, 8.0, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.0])
```

Here's a graphical representation:

[image: example]

I know how to achieve it with a Python loop, but is there a way to do this with NumPy machinery?

Python code for clarity:

```
b = np.array(a)
for i in range(1, b.size):
    if b[i] > b[i-1]:
        b[i] = b[i-1]
```

Comment: Why the concern for "without a loop"? Whether you write an explicit loop, or the loop is done in an imported function from some module/package, it's still there. There aren't very many ways to do something to a series of values that don't involve a loop, unless you want to completely unroll the entire loop into a linear sequence of operations, which is ugly for several different reasons - portability, flexibility, code size, etc...

Comment: @twalberg I think it's common to try to avoid Python loops when using NumPy, because the performance generally improves if the iteration is done inside the functions implemented in C. It also often happens that the code is shorter cleaner.

Comment: That's a valid point when working with large data sets. However, in this example (and without any indication that the "real" problem is orders of magnitude larger), I think the overhead of converting the Python list into a data structure that the C loop can work on, and then converting it back into the appropriate Python data structure, probably voids any potential gain from not just using a Python loop to iterate over a dozen entries... Better to validate that the loop is a problem before just blindly trying to eliminate it...

Comment: @twalberg Fair enough; I should have mentioned that the real data is indeed thousands of elements in size and already in the form of a NumPy array. This question, however, also has an educational purpose.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `np.minimum.accumulate` to collect the minimum values as you move through the array:

```
>>> np.minimum.accumulate(a)
array([ 10. ,   9.5,   8. ,   7.2,   7.2,   7.2,   7. ,   5. ,   3. ,
         2.5,   2.5,   2. ])
```

At each element in the array, this function returns the minimum value seen so far.

If you wanted an array to be monotonic increasing, you could use `np.maximum.accumulate`.

Many other universal functions in NumPy have an [`accumulate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) method to simulate looping through an array, applying the function to each element and collecting the returned values into an array of the same size.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about `.accumulate`! This is very close to Python2 `reduce` (or Python3 `functools.reduce`) , am I correct?

Comment: It's very similar - `accumulate` stores the result of the operation on each element returning an array of the same length, whereas the unfunc's [`reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) method just shows the final result (collapsing the array).

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. So `reduce` would basically return the last element of what `accumulate` returns.