# Determining if an array inside an array is contiguous

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Firstly, I start with sorted trial data:

```
[[ 2,  4,  9, 10, 11],
 [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14],
 [ 3,  6,  8,  8, 11],
 [ 4,  6, 10, 11, 13],
 [ 2,  3,  3,  5,  6],
 [ 3,  5, 12, 12, 13],
 [ 2,  2,  3,  9, 11],
 [ 2,  5, 11, 11, 13],
 [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 10],
 [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14]]
```

Then my goal is return a True or False in the place of each array within and then print out the number of True (contiguous arrays)

So far, I have done this:

```
def isStraight(arr, n):

    for i in range(1,n): 
        if (arr[i] - arr[i-1] > 1) : 
            return 0
    return 1
```

but it returns an error saying

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So I am not sure how to implement another for loop to iterate through the internal arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How do you define whether the array is contiguous or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently check if numpy ndarray values are strictly increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734258/efficiently-check-if-numpy-ndarray-values-are-strictly-increasing)

Comment: @Chris the expected output would be like this [ True True False True False] etc if the arrays go up in sequential order. For example 1 2 3 4 5 would be True, but 1 5 6 3 7 would be False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the array is contiguous if any consecutive elements are with a difference of more than 1, with this try the below code:

```py
a =[[ 2,  4,  9, 10, 11],
 [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14],
 [ 3,  6,  8,  8, 11],
 [ 4,  6, 10, 11, 13],
 [ 2,  3,  3,  5,  6],
 [ 3,  5, 12, 12, 13],
 [ 2,  2,  3,  9, 11],
 [ 2,  5, 11, 11, 13],
 [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 10],
 [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14]]

def isStraight(arr, n):
    for i in range(1,n): 
        if (arr[i] - arr[i-1] > 1) : 
            return 0
    return 1

values = []
for j in a:
    if(isStraight(j, len(j))==1):
        values.append(True)
    else:
        values.append(False)

print(values)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, but this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The output of this code contains a list of true and false. True, indicates that its corresponding array is continuous, and false indicates that its corresponding array is non-continuous. Finally, the number of continuous arrays is shown.

```
def contiguous_arrays(array):
    value=[]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        value.append(array[i]==list(range(min(array[i]),max(array[i])+1)))
    print(value)
    print('Number of continuous arrays:',value.count(True))

array=[[ 2,  4,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14],
       [ 3,  6,  8,  8, 11],
       [ 4,  6, 10, 11, 13],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  5, 12, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  2,  3,  9, 11],
       [ 2,  5, 11, 11, 13],
       [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14]]
contiguous_arrays(array)
# [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]             Number of continuous arrays: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ramin. Please provide some explanation for your answer.