# numpy array set ones between two values, fast

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

having been looking for solution for this problem for a while but can't seem to find anything.

For example,  I have an numpy array of

```
[ 0,  0,  2,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  0,  0, -2, -1, -4, -2, -1, -3, -4,  0,  2,  3, -2, -1,  0]
```

what I would like to achieve is the generate another array to indicate the elements between a pair of numbers, let's say between 2 and -2 here. So I want to get an array like this

```
[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0]
```

Notice any 2 or -2 between a pair of (2, -2) are ignored. Any easy approach is to iterate through each element with for loop and identifies first occurrence of 2 and set everything after that to 1 until you hit an -2 and start look for the next 2 again.

But I would like this process to be faster as I have over 1000 elements in an numpy array. and this process needs to be done a lot of times. Do you guys know any elegant way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where would the range start in `[2, 2, -2]`?

Comment: The first `2`, as is clear from the example: `2,  3,  2, ...`

Comment: Working on something that uses vectorized operations. Haven't quite got it yet, but check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563711/make-a-numpy-array-monotonic-without-a-python-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a problem that is! Listed in this post is a vectorized solution (hopefully the inlined comments would help to explain the logic behind it). I am assuming `A` as the input array with `T1`, `T2` as the start and stop triggers.

```
def setones_between_triggers(A,T1,T2):    

    # Get start and stop indices corresponding to rising and falling triggers
    start = np.where(A==T1)[0]
    stop = np.where(A==T2)[0]

    # Take care of boundary conditions for np.searchsorted to work
    if (stop[-1] < start[-1]) & (start[-1] != A.size-1):
        stop = np.append(stop,A.size-1)

    # This is where the magic happens.
    # Validate (filter out) the triggers based on the set conditions :
    # 1. See if there are more than one stop indices between two start indices.
    # If so, use the first one and rejecting all others in that in-between space.
    # 2. Repeat the same check for start, but use the validated start indices.

    # First off, take care of out-of-bound cases for proper indexing
    stop_valid_idx = np.unique(np.searchsorted(stop,start,'right'))
    stop_valid_idx = stop_valid_idx[stop_valid_idx < stop.size]

    stop_valid = stop[stop_valid_idx]
    _,idx = np.unique(np.searchsorted(stop_valid,start,'left'),return_index=True)
    start_valid = start[idx]

    # Create shifts array (array filled with zeros, unless triggered by T1 and T2 
    # for which we have +1 and -1 as triggers). 
    shifts = np.zeros(A.size,dtype=int)
    shifts[start_valid] = 1
    shifts[stop_valid] = -1

    # Perform cumm. summation that would almost give us the desired output
    out = shifts.cumsum()

    # For a worst case when we have two groups of (T1,T2) adjacent to each other, 
    # set the negative trigger position as 1 as well
    out[stop_valid] = 1    
    return out
```

**Sample runs**

Original sample case :

```
In [1589]: A
Out[1589]: 
array([ 0,  0,  2,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  0,  0, -2, -1, -4, -2, -1, -3, -4,
        0,  2,  3, -2, -1,  0])

In [1590]: setones_between_triggers(A,2,-2)
Out[1590]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Worst case #1 (adjacent `(2,-2)` groups) :

```
In [1595]: A
Out[1595]: 
array([-2,  2,  0,  2, -2,  2,  2,  2,  4, -2,  0, -2, -2, -4, -2, -1,  2,
       -4,  0,  2,  3, -2, -2,  0])

In [1596]: setones_between_triggers(A,2,-2)
Out[1596]: 
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0], dtype=int32)
```

Worst case #2 (`2` without any `-2` till end) :

```
In [1603]: A
Out[1603]: 
array([-2,  2,  0,  2, -2,  2,  2,  2,  4, -2,  0, -2, -2, -4, -2, -1, -2,
       -4,  0,  2,  3,  5,  6,  0])

In [1604]: setones_between_triggers(A,2,-2)
Out[1604]: 
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Ahhh. I had no idea about `searchsorted`. Awesome!

Comment: I was literally about to implement my own ufunc to do this :-).

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah that searchsorted is one of the best tools around :)

Comment: There seems to be a bug. still trying to figure out why. Just post it here and you guys can have a look. I set a = np.random.choice(np.arange(-5, 6), 2000)  and when I run the code it reports an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    stop[np.unique(np.searchsorted(stop,start,'right'))]
IndexError: index 189 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 189.     seems some issue with the index

Comment: @FiniteElement Seems like there was one indeed. Should be fixed in the just completed edits.

Comment: Yes, just found the problem here too. it works! Thanks @Divakar. you are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have got a huge dataset, I prefer to do a pair of initial searches for the two boundaries then use for-loop on these indices for validation.

```
def between_pairs(x, b1, b2):
    # output vector
    out = np.zeros_like(x)

    # reversed list of indices for possible rising and trailing edges
    rise_edges = list(np.argwhere(x==b1)[::-1,0])
    trail_edges = list(np.argwhere(x==b2)[::-1,0])

    # determine the rising trailing edge pairs
    rt_pairs = []
    t = None
    # look for the next rising edge after the previous trailing edge
    while rise_edges:
        r = rise_edges.pop()
        if t is not None and r < t:
            continue

        # look for the next trailing edge after previous rising edge
        while trail_edges:
            t = trail_edges.pop()
            if t > r:
                rt_pairs.append((r, t))
                break

    # use the rising, trailing pairs for updating d
    for rt in rt_pairs:
        out[rt[0]:rt[1]+1] = 1
    return out
# Example
a = np.array([0,  0,  2,  3,  2,  4,  3,  4,  0,  0, -2, -1, -4, -2, -1, -3, -4,
        0,  2,  3, -2, -1,  0])
d = between_pairs(a , 2, -2)
print repr(d)

## -- End pasted text --
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

I did a speed comparison with the alternative answer given by  @CactusWoman

```
def between_vals(x, val1, val2):
    out = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype = int)
    in_range = False
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if v == val1 and not in_range:
            in_range = True
        if in_range:
            out[i] = 1
        if v == val2 and in_range:
            in_range = False
    return out
```

I found the following

```
In [59]: a = np.random.choice(np.arange(-5, 6), 2000)

In [60]: %timeit between_vals(a, 2, -2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 681 µs per loop

In [61]: %timeit between_pairs(a, 2, -2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop
```

and for a much smaller dataset,

```
In [72]: a = np.random.choice(np.arange(-5, 6), 50)

In [73]: %timeit between_vals(a, 2, -2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 17 µs per loop

In [74]: %timeit between_pairs(a, 2, -2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.7 µs per loop
```

Therefore it all depends on your dataset size.

Comment: considering the size of the data we are looking at. This is much better than a simple for loop. Thumbs up for the idea of using bracketing edges.

Comment: @FiniteElement. This answer is obsolete since there is in fact a vectorized solution.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, the vector solution was posted after this.

Answer (score 1):

Is iterating through the array really too slow?

```
def between_vals(x, val1, val2):
    out = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype = int)
    in_range = False
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if v == val1 and not in_range:
            in_range = True
        if in_range:
            out[i] = 1
        if v == val2 and in_range:
            in_range = False
    return out
```

I'm the same boat as @Randy C: nothing else I've tried is faster than this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few things at this point, and the need to keep track of state for the start/finish markers has made the more clever things I've tried slower than the dumb iterative approach I used as a check:

```
for _ in xrange(1000):
    a = np.random.choice(np.arange(-5, 6), 2000)
    found2 = False
    l = []
    for el in a:
        if el == 2:
            found2 = True
        l.append(1 if found2 else 0)
        if el == -2:
            found2 = False
    l = np.array(l)
```